# What are the new unusual effects for Scream Fortress 2014?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Does anyone know what the new effects are? I also heard there are 2 new effects for taunts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are the Unusual effects for hats and taunts in Scream Fortress 2014.**

Hats, from left to right: *Amaranthine,  Bonzo the All-Gnawing, Haunted Phantasm Jr, Ghastly Ghosts Jr, Stare From Beyond, The Ooze.*

[image: Amaranthine Unusual effect]
[image: Bonzo The All-Gnawing Unusual effect]
[image: Haunted Phantasm Jr Unusual effect]
[image: Ghastly Ghosts Jr Unusual effect]
[image: Stare From Beyond Unusual effect]
[image: The Ooze Unusual effect]

Taunts: *Ghastly Ghosts, Haunted Phantasm.*

[image: Ghastly Ghosts Unusual effect]
[image: Haunted Phantasm Unusual effect]

*(There's a chance that the taunt effects and their Jr hat variants may have been mixed up on the wiki, by the looks of it.)*